# The User Name and/or Password are OR is incorrect

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, word-usage

Which of the following would be correct:

1. The User Name and/or Password are incorrect.
2. The User Name and/or Password is incorrect.

Or neither?

Thanks!

Comment: In IT security, it's key not to give away which entry is wrong. Consider that concept in your decision.

Comment: I think replacing 'are' or 'is' with 'are/is' would be correct. Like Yosef Baskin said, you probably want to reword it to 'The user name or password is incorrect.' Neither 'user name' nor 'password' should be capitalized.